# Getting Textbox value in a form

Tags: html, jsp

This is my code:

```
<form method="get" action="http://google.com#q=<%= request.getParameter("myname") %>" target="_blank">
    Enter your name: <input type="text" name="name"><input type="submit">

</form>
```

I need to get the value entered in the textbox to be appended to the URL in the action parameter. How to? The above code returns null for the expression tag.

Comment: you are getting 'myname' as parameter where are your input name is `name`

Comment: Ya i changed it and yet it didn't work pal. Now tried js as @Gal said. Worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<form method="get" action="" target="_blank" id="myForm">
    Enter your name: <input type="text" name="name" id="txtName"><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementById('submit').oncick = function() {
    var val = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
    window.open('http://google.com?q=' + encodeURIComponent(val));
    return false;
}
```

note that if you want the redirect to occur on the same page, use `window.location.href = url` instead of `window.open`

hope that helps.

Comment: Suggesting jQuery solution while OP is not asking for.